# How to set textarea value to a hero text?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a webpage. But it's main is this. If, somebody types something to the textarea, get it's value maybe with javascript, and display it in a hero text. Is it possible?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<h1 id="hero_text"></h1>
<button class="test" id="test">Enter</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "hero text"?

Comment: @AnisR. it's the term used for hugely oversized header images with text (title, author, etc) — if I had had the opportunity I would have voted for "annoying bad idea" but it looks like we're stuck with "hero".

Comment: @Pointy, oh, okay.

Comment: So is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but there are countless ways of doing it and it all depends on what your application is trying to do, and how it works in a larger sense. Stackoverflow is focused on helping with specific problems with specific samples of code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the text that of the hero image is in this:

```
<h1 id='hero_text'></h1>
```

And that your text area is:

```
<textarea id='input'></textarea>
```

Then you can use the textarea's `onchange` event to track when the user changes the text in the textarea, and update the hero text accordingly:

**EDIT: To track changes while the user is typing (not after they de-select the textarea, use `oninput` instead of `onchange`).**

```
var h1 = document.getElementById('hero_text');
var textarea = document.getElementById('input');
textarea.oninput = function() {
  //note that inside this event handler, 'this' points to the textarea
  h1.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

**Edit 2:** Here's a snippet that's based on the code you just provided:

```js
var h1 = document.getElementById('hero_text');
var textarea = document.getElementById('input');
var btn = document.getElementById('test');
btn.onclick = function() {
  //note that inside this event handler, 'this' points to the button
  h1.innerHTML = textarea.value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1
{
    margin-left: 500px;
}

</style>

<script src="test.js"></script>


<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<h1 id="hero_text"></h1>
<button class="test" id="test">Enter</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok. I will try it now. Thank you!

Comment: I tried it. Nothing happens. For just test, I moved the hero to margin_left: 500px and tried to write something in it. But if I type something nothing happens. :(

Comment: I've tried in a code demo. It's working. I've to check my code. By the way, is it possible to do the same but with a submit button or something like that. Thank you!

Comment: @LogRol I edited my post a few minutes ago. Hope the edit helps.

Comment: @LogRol Yes, it is possible with a button. Simply add a button and handle its `onclick` event accordingly. However, do not set the button's type to be `type='submit'`, as this makes the page to reload. Use `type='button'` instead.

Comment: Yea I saw the changes. Not working. Maybe help if I send the code?

Comment: @LogRol Yes, please edit your post by adding relevant code.

Comment: I saw. I copied the code and pasted to the index.html, and test.js file. Still nothing happens.

Comment: In the snippet it is working, so I suspect your previous version of test.js is cached in your browser. Make sure you "hard reload" your HTML file, to make sure your javascript will be refreshed. On Chrome, it's Ctrl+Shift+R. Plus now, the text will be changed only when you click on the button, as requested.

Comment: Tried it. Still nothing happens. What's going on?

Comment: For a try, I uploaded the html to a website. Still not working at here. Link: https://atclogrol.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: @LogRol Oh, now that I came back at it, it was just a variable name error! Sorry for that! Answer updated. I don't know how the code snippet was running fine though...

Comment: Hi! I've updated the code as you requested, but still not working at the webpage, and the html file. (Not working, if I open the HTML file, and not working inside a website where I uploaded the html and javascript.)